# How to call calabash xml from a Java program

Tags: spring-mvc, xproc

I try to set up a web based application using spring and xslt. Since i always use xslt in a pipelining style, i would like to use calabash. Is there a possibility to call calabash from Java? I read thru the documentation on http://xmlcalabash.com but there is only a description how to use it from command line. I also tired to find some javadoc on githup but wasn't successful. Obviously, there is the Main class with the main() method and i could supply the command line parameters as a string array...

I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this recently too. I took a pragmatic approach where I call Main.run(), and pass in a string array that I generate from a (File)Properties object. It doesn't allow passing in file inputs as streams or sources however, they must reside on the file-system.

Likely there are nicer ways. You could for instance look into http://expath.org/ . There should be sources of that project. The webapp modules (formerly known as servlex?) seems to provide XMLCalabash integration.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for the link, i try to have a look at it as soon as possible.